# composer require laravel/passport not working in laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8, laravel-passport

I'm using Laravel 5.8 although `6.0.3` is available. I'm using it because the tutorial I'm following is using Laravel 5.8.

When, I command:

```sh
composer require laravel/passport
```

it throws an error

> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
>
> Problem 1
>       - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v5.8.35
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.35
>       - laravel/passport 8.x-dev requires illuminate/encryption ^6.0|^7.0 -> satisfiable by illuminate/encryption[6.x-dev, 7.0.x-dev, v6.0.0, v6.0.1, v6.0.2, v6.0.3, v6.0.4, v6.1.0, v6.2.0, v6.3.0, v6.4.1].
>       - laravel/passport v8.0.0 requires illuminate/encryption ^6.0|^7.0 -> satisfiable by illuminate/encryption[6.x-dev, 7.0.x-dev, v6.0.0, v6.0.1, v6.0.2, v6.0.3, v6.0.4, v6.1.0, v6.2.0, v6.3.0, v6.4.1].
>       - don't install illuminate/encryption 6.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.35
>       - don't install illuminate/encryption 7.0.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.35
>       - don't install illuminate/encryption v6.0.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.35
>       - don't install illuminate/encryption v6.0.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.35
>       - don't install illuminate/encryption v6.0.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.35
>       - don't install illuminate/encryption v6.0.3|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.35
>       - don't install illuminate/encryption v6.0.4|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.35
>       - don't install illuminate/encryption v6.1.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.35
>       - don't install illuminate/encryption v6.2.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.35
>       - don't install illuminate/encryption v6.3.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.35
>       - don't install illuminate/encryption v6.4.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.35
>       - Installation request for laravel/framework (locked at v5.8.35, required as 5.8.*) -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.8.35].
>       - Installation request for laravel/passport ^8.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/passport[8.x-dev, v8.0.0].
>
> Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.

Answer (score 47):

Latest version of `Laravel Passport` dropped support for `Laravel 5.8`

Install earlier version

```
composer require laravel/passport:7.5.1
```

From [the release notes of Laravel Passport](https://github.com/laravel/passport/releases/tag/v8.0.0)

#### Changed

- Rework HandlesOAuthErrors trait to middleware (#937)
- Use a renderable exception for OAuth errors (#1066)
- Use diactoros 2.0 and psr-http-factory (aadf603)
- Replaced helpers with Blade directives (#939)
- Use caret for constraints (d906804)
- Dropped support for Laravel 5.8 [(654cc09)](https://github.com/laravel/passport/commit/654cc09b06b600c5629497aa2567be44c285d113)
- Dropped support for PHP 7.1 (3c830ac)
- Upgrade to league/oauth2-server 8.0 (97e3026)

Comment: getting this warning `Warning from https://repo.packagist.org: You are using an outdated version of Composer. Composer 2.0 is now available and you should upgrade. See https://getcomposer.org/2` and passport doesn't installed as well.

Comment: getting this error: ` [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]                                                                                                      
  The "http://repo.packagist.org/p/laravel/passport%24a752029de59be2bf80a8a2966ee5874c6f74fc8c5a3d3cd6127a9849bb08b5cc.json" file could not be  
   downloaded: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.                                                             
  failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.`

Comment: This worked for me composer require laravel/passport:^9.0

Answer (score 11):

install with the option --with-all-dependencies, it with upgrade, downgrades and remove packages locked to specific version

`composer require laravel/passport --with-all-dependencies`

Comment: This one worked for me for Laravel 9.34.0

Answer (score 5):

You can use this command to install passport on laravel 5.8 projects: `composer require laravel/passport "7.5.1"` or you can include passport in composer dependecies:

```
"require": {
    ...
    "laravel/passport": "7.5.1",
    ....
}
```

and then run `composer update` Both will install passport in your project.

Answer (score 3):

composer require laravel/passport works on the latest version of laravel.

You have to download the version according to your laravel version.

So to solve, go-to Laravel docs and select the version you are currently running and then go to Passport it will show you the appropriate version of Passport to install for your version of laravel.

Comment: Good Solution @kp85.. I was facing the same problem with lots of packages in my laravel 7. I updated all of them according to the command given on the laravel docs

Comment: for laravel 6 docs, they did not specify the version of passport.

Answer (score 3):

Try to install using this command

```
composer require laravel/passport --with-all-dependencies
```

it will work!

Answer (score 0):

It is just a version issue!
The below command works for me.

composer require laravel/passport --ignore-platform-reqs